# What setting controls auto closing quote mark behavior in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I type a ' in Visual Studio a second ' is entered form me automatically. Occasionally this is helpful but for my work it will be more helpful if I can turn it off. I don't know which option of Visual Studio is controlling this. I searched intellisense and auto complete but did not find it. I do have several extensions installed including Productivity Power Tools 2017.

How can I disable/enable this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 'automatic brace completion', via:

Menu Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Automatic brace completion

Unfortunately there is no separate option to only apply this for quotes; when disabled you also don't have it for eg. braces, brackets, etc.